# How to connect to my Raspberry Pi over the internet, rather than inside the LAN?

Tags: python, networking, routes, raspberry-pi, ip

I have a python TCP server on raspberry Pi zero WH. The RPi is connected to Wi-Fi and it has access to Internet. I can connect to Raspberry via ssh or VNC and to the server by application on android. The problem is that I can only connect by local IP (192.168...) so I must do it from computer or phone in the same Wi-Fi network.

I didn't try everything, but I think that I could simply call my Internet provider about external IP. But this would work only in my home network and if I for example take my RPi to work, I could't connect to it.

So what can I do to connect to my Raspberry by Internet, from other network?

Comment: Check this out... https://lifehacker.com/how-to-control-a-raspberry-pi-remotely-from-anywhere-in-1792892937 But you might need to set it up again if you move take the pi to your work. So it probably won't help you that much

Comment: If I well understand it solves the problem with VNC connect, but what with connecting to server from app? I do it by socket and I must give IP adress. This will work for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access your RPi directly from the internet because it is probably connected to the internet using your router, which probably uses PAT (a type of [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)).

That means that when your RPi accesses the internet, it does that through your router, using its public IP. That also means that it doesn't have a public IP of itself and can't receive direct communication from the internet.

A possible solution would be to configure port forwarding on your router (here's an example [guide](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-port-forward-4163829)). That would allow you to tell your router to accept connections on a specific port, and just forward these connections to your RPi on a specific port.

This solution is not ideal bacuse:

- It will only work in your home network
- It will require you to configure a static IP for you RPi
- It will require you to verify with your internet provider that your router's public IP will not change
- It will stop working if you ever replace your router or factory-reset it.

So you might want to check some other options. There are some popular choices [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/access-over-Internet/).

Comment: Thanks, I think that it coul;d be problem with router, beacuse I have Wi-Fi from my presonal router, but this one is connected wirely to router from Internet provider... And to this router I haven't access :(

If I connect RPi by Sim Card, I will have an external IP?

Comment: Actually, a SIM card would probably not help as I just found out you're usually connected to a mobile network behind a NAT as well :( I'll modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

easiest solution is to install some remote control software such as teamviewer or anydesk on raspberry pi, setup unattended access, then use the same software on ur mac/pc to get remote access, you get a graphical user interface, so u will need to have auto login setup on raspberry pi.

you can download anydesk from this link:
https://anydesk.com/en/downloads/raspberry-pi

team viewer:
open terminal on raspberry pi and use the following commands

wget https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer-host_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer-host_armhf.deb

if u only want terminal access use something like Dataplicity

Comment: It's good solution, but only to connect with Raspberry itself, but it wouldn't work for server. I can't connect my android app by those programs, I nedd IP.